# Can I charge from portable battery on a Late 2013 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, charging

I don't know a lot about the in's and out's of Apple charging devices.

I have a RavPower 26800 PD USB type C battery, and they are meant to be able to charge a MacBook of various descriptions at least once. I have a similar Anker one but less powerful.

I have a late 2013 MacBook Pro, so it has what I understand is a MagSafe 2 adapter on it. Its also got what looks like Thunderbolt inputs? There must be a way to charge my MacBook from the USB type C battery's thunderbolt port? Or a converter into the original power input?

Comment: USB 3.1 PD is a *negotiated* connection; meaning it's not compatible.  Period.  By the time you "engineer" a way to get it to charge of of the USB-C battery bank, you could have sourced a battery with an inverter.  Or better yet - get a [12V car adapter](https://amzn.to/2GYFtq1)

Answer (score 3):

You would need an inverter to go from USB-C Power Delivery's DC to AC to Apple's Magsafe 2 DC adapter. Going DC to AC and then from AC to DC is inefficient. Also, as far as I can tell, a USB-C PD inverter doesn't exist.

As a quick note: MacBooks with Thunderbolt 1 and 2 do not support charging via their Thunderbolt ports, only via Magsafe. Thunderbolt 3 supports USB-C Power Delivery and MacBooks with Thunderbolt 3 / USB-C ports charge exclusively through them.

Let's consider a new battery that has an AC outlet. [RavPower makes a battery pack with an AC socket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072VHJZDV), but you are hard-pressed to get a single charge for a Magsafe-based laptop. [Anker makes the PowerHouse 2](https://www.anker.com/deals/powerhouse2), a $500 beast that could charge a recent MacBook Pro 13" about 6 times. (*If* The PowerHouse had USB-C PD ports, the number of MacBook recharges would certainly be higher, but wouldn't do you any good, as your Late-2013 MacBook Pro uses Magsafe.)

This is assuming that portability is key. If you are in a car (or have a 12V battery that you can clip into), [a power inverter could be acceptable](https://www.amazon.com/Power-Inverters/b?ie=UTF8&node=583328).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I charge from portable battery on a Late 2013 MacBook Pro?

**No**.

The RavPower 26800 PD USB type C battery can be used to charge MacBook's and MacBook Pro's with USB type C port. This include the new Retina MacBook introduced in 2015 and later, and the fourth generation MacBook Pro with Touch Bar and USB C ports introduced in Late 2016 and later.

Comment: oh ok, thanks - Is there no way to go from magsafe to a usb C input adapter? Thanks for all your messages

Comment: While there are various MagSafe 2 to USB Type C adapters (you can do a Web search), but I couldn't find any available the other way round (as required in your case).